# What is considered the current industry standard alternative to CGI for Python web development?

Tags: python, cgi

For one of my classes last semester I had to create a website using a CGI script. While it was a good introduction to web development, but I can see it has it's limitations. So my question is, in the industry today, what is the most common approach for parsing a Python script into html?

I have found a few posts on Stack Overflow that suggest FastCGI for PHP, but I am wondering if the same answers apply to Python.

Comment: CGI scripts are very outdated. You don't parse Python script into HTML anymore either. Try looking into Flask + Jinja templates

Comment: Thanks! I know this may be an entirely different question, but if I use something like Jinja, I assume that I would use .py rather than .cgi? If that's the case, how would a web server know to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume that I would use .py rather than .cgi? If that's the case, how would a web server know to run it?

This is a old way of thinking :)

Nowadays you [start your Python process](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application), and it begins to listen on a port. The Python process itself contains a webserver and is almost completely self-contained - [see here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/) for the different webservers you can use within your Python process - gunicorn is a popular one.

Of course a lot of people still put Nginx or Apache in front of their Python process as a "reverse proxy". Essentially this is to handle SSL/TLS but also sometimes to do load balancing, custom error pages if your Python process is down etc.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very insightful.

Answer (score 2):

WSGI is a protocol that describes (synchronous) communication between a web server and a web application. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface